# Close/exit active tab no matter what

Tags: vim

Usually in vim to exit doing `:q` will work, however, sometimes if it's not the primary tab, exiting is only achieved by doing `:clo` (and then it's a bit different to close a `:term` window).

Is is possible to write a keyboard shortcut that will close the active tab -- no matter what it consists of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
nnoremap <Leader>x :bd!<CR>
```

For further info see: `:h bd`